# Two stroke engine dies at full throttle

Tags: small-engine, trimmer

I've got a two stroke strimmer (new last summer). It starts fine and responds smoothly to the throttle but approaching full throttle it cuts out.

I've tried changing the fuel for carefully measured fresh mix. The air filter is clean and afaik there is no fuel filter to check.

My barn is fairly open and I wonder whether water has got in, but it strikes me the symptoms are wrong. Also the cylinder can be seen through the exhaust port and at high throttle it glows orange. Is that normal?

Anyone got any ideas? Dismantle the carb perhaps? Hope not... Thanks.

Comment: Just yank the carb off completely and try to run it. If it runs fine then you know its a carb issue. If it is a carb issue and the bowl looks fairly clean than its probably the needle and seat. Run it through a parts washer if you have one. That being said this is probably not the place for this question so I am going to try and have it moved to the Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair community.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the brand/model of the trimmer? As far as seeing orange through the exhaust port, I'm surprised it doesn't have a muffler of some sort blocking your view. Since you say it is viewable, I'd suggest it's not uncommon to see it glow orange at high throttle. The reason for this is it being a 2-stroke engine. Most 2-strokes are not very efficient and will burn part of the air/fuel mixture as it's leaving the exhaust port. You're most likely just seeing the burn.

Comment: With trimmer power problems, I always check the spark suppressor screen on the exhaust.  Esp with 2-strokes.

Comment: Thanks for some helpful ideas. It's a Hyundai hyft56. Tried it again yesterday and it's rougher than ever. I'm thinking I might start with a carb cleaner spray...